# can't download github project with curl command

Tags: bash, curl, github, download, command

I used "curl -sO" command to download project files from this GitHub project link:
http://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip

but, I couldn't download. There is error occured and says that:

```
Archive:  /home/ziyaddin/Desktop/master.zip
[/home/ziyaddin/Desktop/master.zip]   End-of-central-directory
signature not found.  Either this file is not   a zipfile, or it
constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the   latter case
the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on   the last
disk(s) of this archive. zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in
one of /home/ziyaddin/Desktop/master.zip or
          /home/ziyaddin/Desktop/master.zip.zip, and cannot find 
/home/ziyaddin/Desktop/master.zip.ZIP, period.
```

but I can download this link with curl command:
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/pivotal/jasmine/jasmine-standalone-1.3.1.zip

I think that it is because it is in cloud.github.com. I want to know how can I download from  first link with curl command?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
curl -L -O https://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip
```

- you must use `https://`
- you must use `-L` to follow redirects

Answer (score 11):

`curl -JLO "https://github.com/tada/pljava/archive/V1_6_2.zip"`

-J, --remote-header-name  Use the header-provided filename (H).
-L, --location      Follow redirects (H).
-O, --remote-name   Write output to a file named as the remote file.

Gist [Reference](https://gist.github.com/lemenkov/1674929)

Answer (score 8):

You can also download a `tarball` (***.tar.gz**) with:

```
curl -LkSs https://api.github.com/repos/ziyaddin/xampp/tarball -o master.tar.gz
```

or if you use the `-O` you can omit the filename, but then your saved ".tar.gz" file, is named by default to "tarball", so you have to rename it and add the ".tar.gz" filetype postfix. So use the (lowercase) `-o` as above. The rest:

- `Ss` - use silent mode, but show errors, if any
- `k` - use an *insecure* SSL connection without checking the TLS cert.
- `L` - use to follow HTTP redirects.
- `O` - use original filename when saving.
- `o` - use specified filename when saving.

Comment: why would you want to use `-k`?

Comment: Because the cert may be *expired, invalid, self-signed* or perhaps the connection is made through a proxy, or you may not (want to) have the cert. Otherwise you have to specify it with `--cacert`, depending on your OS and setup. See [here](https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html) and [here](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--cacert).

Comment: What libcurl is verifying is the server-side certificate. Unless you're hitting a local server with a self-signed certificate, you shouldn't be using `-k` because it makes your connection inherently insecure and vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ curl -I http://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Sun, 28 Apr 2013 09:24:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: close
Location: https://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

... so you need to use `-L` if you want to follow the HTTP redirect. Or just read Steven Penny's answer...

Answer (score 1):

One thing not mentioned in the above answers is **what if you have a really large file** such that when you go to that file in a GitHub repository, you see a message that says:

```
(Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.)
```

[image: screen shot of note from GitHub that file is too large to display]

To download such a large file requires adding an argument to the URL of `?raw=true` as in the following `curl` command example:

```
curl -L https://github.com/opengenpos/buildproducts/blob/main/GenPOS_rel_02_03_01_013.exe?raw=true >jkjk.exe
```

This results in the following output in a Windows command shell window:

```
C:\Users\rickc\Documents>curl -L https://github.com/opengenpos/buildproducts/blob/main/GenPOS_rel_02_03_01_013.exe?raw=true >jkjk.exe
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   146  100   146    0     0    146      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   491
100   157  100   157    0     0    157      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  153k
100 15.7M  100 15.7M    0     0  15.7M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 12.7M

C:\Users\rickc\Documents>
```

and the file is downloaded to a local file named `jkjk.exe`.

**Note:** Windows 10 now has both `tar` and `curl` as standard commands now see [Tar and Curl Come to Windows!](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409):

> Beginning in Insider Build 17063, we’re introducing two command-line
> tools to the Windows toolchain: `curl` and `bsdtar`. It’s been a long
> time coming, I know. We'd like to give credit to the folks who’ve
> created and maintain `bsdtar` and `curl` — awesome open-source tools
> used by millions of humans every day. Let's take a look at two
> impactful ways these tools will make developing on Windows an even
> better experience.