# Download github release with curl

Tags: curl, github

On [this URL](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v0.23.4/yarn-v0.23.4.tar.gz) I'm able to download a .tar.gz which contains an official release. (I know it's also available on an API endpoint but this contains the test package too.

Now I'm wondering why this isn't working:

```
$ curl -O https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v0.23.4/yarn-v0.23.4.tar.gz
```

I get some `.tar.gz` which is 4KB instead of 3.6MB. It isn't showing an error. What am I missing? I want to use this URL and not the API if that's possible.

Comment: Check this reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/66286953/5078874

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If you do the following it will download correctly:

```
wget https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v0.23.4/yarn-v0.23.4.tar.gz
```

If you want to use curl you have to use the redirect `-L` option to follow redirect link and direct the output in a file like this:

```sh
curl -L https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v0.23.4/ya‌​rn-v0.23.4.tar.gz > yarn.tar.gz
```

Comment: Or alternatively do `curl -OL <link>` to automatically select filename.

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/jwebcat/5122366) also has a pretty good discussion on what those flags are and why use them.

In case you don't feel like scrolling the the man page.

Answer (score 5):

## 2021 Update Download from GitHub Using wget

**Will also expand and delete the archive. Just edit the REPLACE_ values and then copy/paste**

### tgz

```
GH_USER=REPLACE_WITH_USER \
GH_REPO=REPLACE_WITH_REPO \
GH_BRANCH=REPLACE_WITH_BRANCH \
wget https://github.com/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/archive/refs/tags/${GH_BRANCH}.tar.gz \
-O "${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.tar.gz" && \
tar -xzvf ./"${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.tar.gz" && \
rm ./"${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.tar.gz"
```

### zip

```
GH_USER=REPLACE_WITH_USER \
GH_REPO=REPLACE_WITH_REPO \
GH_BRANCH=REPLACE_WITH_BRANCH \
wget https://github.com/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/archive/refs/tags/${GH_BRANCH}.zip \
-O "${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.zip" && \ 
unzip ./"${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.zip" && \
rm ./"${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.zip"
```

Comment: Looks like this downloads the source distribution. The OP is trying to download the release binaries.